# How to speed up TFS in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I click on a folder in TFS inside Visual Studio, it literally takes 4-5 seconds for the IDE to respond.  It used to be instantaneous.  The hard drive at this time is going nuts.

I used `procmon` to see what is going on and it seems that every time I click on a folder (or expand it), devenv.exe process literally scan every file in my workspace.

It's a good thing I have an SSD - otherwise it would take more than 4 seconds.

Why does it scan all these files?
How do I stop it?
How do I restore the speediness?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a particularly large workspace, you might try using a Server workspace instead of a Local workspace (you do this from the Workspaces... dialog in VS).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  Can you shed some light on why?

Comment: Server workspaces keep track of your pending changes on the server, local workspaces will continuously scan your filesystem to dynamically detect changes.  Usually people prefer local workspaces as they provide some extra flexibility, but there is a performance cost.  Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx